# Filter last n observations in a timestamp R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I'm a novice in R and I have a simple question.

I have a dataframe where I have a column on timestamp and various other features. The timestamp column is of 31 days and I have to get the last n days (lets say 16) of the time stamp.

Assuming 31 days, it will then give me the observations from the last 16 days (16th-Oct to 31st-Oct). I know how to do this in Python but I have no clue how to do this in R.

Sample df:

```
f1 f2 f3 timestamp
1  2  3  2020-10-02 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-03 14:26:03
1  2  3  2020-10-05 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-05 14:26:03
1  2  3  2020-10-07 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-10 14:26:03
1  2  3  2020-10-12 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-13 14:26:03
1  2  3  2020-10-15 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-16 14:26:03
1  2  3  2020-10-22 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-25 14:26:03
1  2  3  2020-10-26 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-31 14:26:03
```

What the result should look like:

```
f1 f2 f3 timestamp
2  3  5  2020-10-16 14:26:03
1  2  3  2020-10-22 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-25 14:26:03
1  2  3  2020-10-26 14:36:03
2  3  5  2020-10-31 14:26:03
```

The time in the timestamp is different for each observation and the frame above is just for illustration purposes.
Any help would be appreciated.

Update to remove confusion:

I can't use the tail() function as in the original dataframe, there are multiple values per day. Apologies for not making it clear.

Comment: Try to use dput() with your data.frame and post the result. Then one can directly try with your example data

Comment: The `tail` function `tail(df, n)` will return the last `n` rows of a data frame. E.g. `last8 <- tail(mtcars, 8)`

Comment: @SteveM I can't use the tail function because there are multiple values per day. is there any alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need `lubridate` within `subset`

```
library(lubridate)
subset(
  df,
  day(timestamp) >= days_in_month(timestamp) - 15
)
```

or in a `dplyr` manner

```
df %>%
  filter(between(day(timestamp), days_in_month(timestamp) - 15, days_in_month(timestamp)))
```

which gives

```
   f1 f2 f3           timestamp
10  2  3  5 2020-10-16 14:26:03
11  1  2  3 2020-10-22 14:36:03
12  2  3  5 2020-10-25 14:26:03
13  1  2  3 2020-10-26 14:36:03
14  2  3  5 2020-10-31 14:26:03
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(f1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), f2 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L,
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), f3 = c(3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L,
3L, 5L, 3L, 5L), timestamp = structure(c(1601642163, 1601727963,
1601901363, 1601900763, 1602074163, 1602332763, 1602506163, 1602591963,
1602765363, 1602851163, 1603370163, 1603632363, 1603719363, 1604150763
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA,
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Works perfect. I was not aware of this method. Will read more about it.

Comment: @SyedAhmed I simplified my answer so you can check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you need to first order your dataframe then use order, afterwards you can simply use `unique` with `tail` to get the dates and then simply filter your dataframe. I assume with timestamp you mean `POSIXct` class in R, then try

```r
data <- data.frame(
  f1 = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
  timestamp = as.POSIXct(c(
    "2020-10-02 14:36:03",
    "2020-10-03 14:26:03",
    "2020-10-05 14:36:04",
    "2020-10-05 14:36:04",
    "2020-10-05 14:36:04",
    "2020-10-05 14:36:05"
  ))
)
data_ordered <- data[order(as.Date(data$timestamp)),]
dates <- tail(unique(data_ordered$timestamp), 2)

data_ordered[data_ordered$timestamp %in% dates, ]
```

without ordering you can of course directly call `tail()` on your dataframe.

**Alternative:**

The above version is base R, you could also solve your problem a bit easier using the `tidyverse` or `data.table`

Alternative 1: tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
data <- as_tibble(data)
data %>% filter(timestamp %in% dates)
```

Alternative 2: data.table

```r
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
data[timestamp %in% dates]
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I can't use the tail function because there are multiple values per day. is there any alternative.